# Show attributes in custom prouduct template

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce

Trying to parse attributes through custom product loop for custom product  template

I'm able to get image and title but not attributes. I have this error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_attribute()

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
global $product;

$taxrates = $wpdb->get_results($query);

foreach ($taxrates as $taxrate) {
    echo get_attribute($taxrate->products_id( 'pa_info' ));

    echo get_the_title($taxrate->products_id);
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($taxrate->products_id);
    echo $taxrate->rate_2;
    echo $taxrate->rate_2;
    echo $taxrate->rate_3;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_post_meta to read attributes.

For example, I am reading _sale_price of a product

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($product->ID, "_sale_price", true); ?>
```

or WC_Product object instance

```
$value= WC_Product::get_attribute( 'attribute_name' );
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks but found a fix it needed to parse through $taxrate like this

```
array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $taxrate->products_id, 'pa_info', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) )
```

now trying to parse external cart link `<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>`

but get

> Fatal error: Call to a member function add_to_cart_url() on a
>   non-object in

any suggestions